# What is the role of "drive" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, nouns, parts-of-speech

that is the HeadLine on new york times:

"Google Employees Brace for a Cost-Cutting Drive as Anxiety Mounts"

is "drive" here a noun meaning something like an effort?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a noun.

You know it is a noun because it has an article "a ... Drive".  Only nouns can take the article "a".

You may check the meaning in a dictionary, "an effort" would be a reasonable gloss.